# Do i need mutex, when i just access map of net.Conn in different goroutines and write to them

Tags: go, mutex

Do i need mutex in this case ?

I have a simple type with map of net.Conn

```go
type ConnectionsHandler struct {
    mutex                 sync.Mutex
    connections           map[string]net.Conn
    authorizedConnections []string
}
```

And when i need to add or remove connection from different goroutines, i think i need to use mutex for thread safety

```go
func (c *ConnectionsHandler) addConnection(conn net.Conn, id string) {
    c.mutex.Lock()
    c.connections[id] = conn
    c.mutex.Unlock()
}

func (c *ConnectionsHandler) removeConnection(id string) {
    c.mutex.Lock()

    if conn, ok := c.connections[id]; ok {
        conn.Close()
        delete(c.connections, id)
    }

    c.mutex.Unlock()
}
```

But i also need for iterate over all connections and write to them, or write to single one

```go
func (c *ConnectionsHandler) sendMessage(msg GameMessage) {
    // write msg to specific single one
}

func (c *ConnectionsHandler) sendMessageToAll(msg GameMessage) {
    // iterate over all connections and write msg to them
}
```

And the question is, do i need mutex lock in `sendMessageToAll()` when i call `Write()` on each net.Conn stored in map ??

Comment: If sendMessage and sendMessageToAll can be called concurrently with addConnection or removeConnection, then you must protect access to the map in sendMessage and sendMessageToAll with the mutex.

Comment: If sendMessage* functions access the connections map, then they must lock the mutex, or only be invoked while holding the mutex. Even if they are not invoked concurrently with the add/remove methods. Otherwise, no happens-before relationship between earlier writes and the read exists, and we have a read-write data race.